# How do I exclude "Merge pull request #17 from me/my-branch" type commit messages?

Tags: git, github

I have a Github repo and follow the [Github flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/) method to add commits to my repo. I then open up the pull request, approve and merge it. However, my `git log` shows 2 commits:

```
commit 9876543 (HEAD -> master, origin/master)
Merge: abcdefg 123456
Author: Me <1234567+Me@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Fri Apr 23 9:42:31 2021 -0500

    Merge pull request #17 from me/my-branch
    
    This is the commit message

commit 123456 (origin/my-branch, my-branch)
Author: Me <1234567+Me@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Fri Apr 23 9:41:17 2021 -0500

    This is the commit message
```

The most recent commit seems to just duplicate the first and seems totally unnecessary. How do I exclude it? I don's seen any options in my Github settings to do it.

Comment: If you're making and reviewing your own PRs the whole _flow_ seems unnecessary. But if you don't want merge commits, use the squash or rebase options; see https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-pull-request-merges.

Comment: Why don't you just not open a pull request for a single commit in your own repository?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I did it for a single commit. The latest commit is what Github added

Comment: @jonrsharpe I like to work on multiple branches of different things at different times. The squash won't work because the pull request is just a single commit. The second commit happens when Github merges it.

Comment: Squash and rebase will both happily take a single commit (with the same result; they're only different with _multiple_ commits). And you can work on branches to your heart's content without ever having to go through the PR; just bring that work into your default branch with a _local_ merge, rebasing branches if necessary to keep those merges clean (you either either squash or fast-forward them to taste).

Comment: I like to have people review my changes so gonna go with the pull request.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid seeing merge commits, use `git log --no-merges`.

To avoid creating merge commits, select "Rebase and Merge" instead of "Merge pull request" when accepting a pull request on GitHub.

Comment: Note, however, that rebase-and-merge always *copies* the original commit(s) to new ones, even if a fast-forward would have been possible. This potentially creates annoyances (one must know when to discard one's local commits).

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing pull requests and people are reviewing them and you are doing a proper merge at the end when the code is approved, then the existence of a merge commit expressing the fact that the pull request was approved and the branch was merged *is correct*. That is what a pull request *is:* it is a merge request where the merge is performed at the remote repository (GitHub or whatever).

> The most recent commit seems to just duplicate the first and seems totally unnecessary

It is *not* totally unnecessary. This is the merge commit, the commit with two parents (the old `master` and your `my-branch`) that combines the contribution from both sides of the merge. That is what a merge *is*: it is the creation of a merge commit.

So don't worry, be happy, and move on. This is how pull requests work, to get the nice "train track" topology expressing the history. It's not bad, it's good.

Comment: "That is what a merge *is*: it is the creation of a merge commit.". Except if your merge is a "Rebase and Merge" on GitHub right? Then it's not really a merge, just a coming together of branches?

Comment: Hi @HeathRaftery! Note the first sentence of my answer: "If you are doing pull requests and people are reviewing them and you are doing a proper merge at the end". The Rebase option is not a proper merge; it's not a merge at all, it's a rebase.

Comment: Right, and that's a useful point to make, since the OP reasonably wondered "I don't seen any options in my Github", and it's not entirely intuitive that "Rebase and merge" actually means "Rebase but don't do a proper merge". In fact, I think it means do a ff merge, which **may** (if the branch is up to date) just move the HEAD and not perform a merge at all. So by "proper" you mean (at least) "not ff"?

Comment: @HeathRaftery Fast forward isn't a merge either. A merge is a thing that makes a merge commit. It's a tautology.

Comment: @HeathRaftery And "not entirely intuitive" is beautifully euphemistic. These names are _atrocious_. Rebase and merge is not a merge. Squash and merge is not a merge. GitHub misleads so many people with those names! Those two are the _opposite_ of merges.

Comment: Nice, that corroborates my suspicions. Though in GH's defence (criticism still extremely valid!), `git` puts `--ff` as an option to `merge`, stating "With --ff, when possible resolve the merge as a fast-forward (only update the branch pointer to match the merged branch; do not create a merge commit). When not possible, create a merge commit.", so they kinda started the confusion - GitHub just popularised it ;-)

Comment: @HeathRaftery Totally. Git's terminology is seriously misleading too. Don't get me started. (Ooops, too late.)